# Composed task custom condition

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Is it possible to create a custom Exit status in spring cloud data flow?

Let's say i have the following:
[image]

I saw an examples for `FAILED` and `UNKNOWN`, so I've created 2 custom conditions `Worked` & `Generated`.
Assuming this approach is possible - How do i pass those strings from inside the task? Or it needs to be passed from somewhere else?
If not - then why i can write any string that i want in the "Properties for TRANSITION" modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than providing the UI option to wire the exit-code to map to a particular downstream step, there's nothing dynamically influenced by SCDF. In other words, SCDF doesn't interfere with whatever is happening internally in each Task application.

The custom transitions *require* the desired exit-codes to be returned/handled within the Task application itself.

In your example above, if the `Timestamp`'s business logic returned "Worked" as the exit-code, then the transition would result in executing `Bar` application. Likewise, if the exit-code is "Generated", you'd see `Foo` running.

Comment: But where and how (in the code itself) i can return those values? The 'Task' is basically a spring boot app with a 'main' method (which is void), and the task bean is a 'run' method (which is also void), so how do i pass this value from inside the `Timestamp` app to the 'orchestra tor' app?

Comment: First, of all, you need to read more about [how exit-message works](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-task-execution-listener-exit-messages) in Spring Cloud Task. Also, read more about how these [maps to exit-status](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_exit_statuses) in SCDF.

Comment: Of course, the stock `timestamp` app that we ship won't magically work with whatever transition you are wanting to explore. You need to build a custom task app to add and map your "custom" exit-message to whatever you want, and then build the composed task graph in SCDF to create the transitions. Again, it has to be done in your app.

Comment: The CTR expert in the team pointed me to his end-to-end sample that demonstrates the exit-message functionality, locally and also in SCDF. See: https://github.com/cppwfs/funwithctr

Comment: Thank you @Shabby Anandan for the explanations, this was very helpful, and it did solved my issue :)